# django - model - what are the benefits?

Tags: python, django

I have customized my Django project to work with mariaDB (mySQL).
Works fine, however I have issues (or concerns) with models.

First of all - I am not sure why I should need them if for me (personally) its much easier to use SQL statements to get the data.
Using API for DB queries might be useful for people who do not know SQL, but for me its less flexible.
Can anybody explain me main benefits of using models?

Here is one of the issues I have. See the code below.

```
class Quotes(models.Model):
    updated = models.DateTimeField()
    tdate = models.DateField(default='1900-01-01')
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    open = models.FloatField(default=0)
    vol = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

1. why program does not consider 'default' when DB table and fields are created?
2. why - what I define as FloatField on DB is 'double' and not 'float' (I checked this using phpMYAdmin)

How can I properly set default value?

My table will have at least 1 million of entries. 
Do I need to concern about performance using API instead of direct SQL queries?  Usually one query will select 700-800 entries.
Is it good approach to use MySQLdb and direct SQL's instead of models?

sorry that some questions might sound too simple, but I just started with Django. Before this I worked with PHP. Main reason I want to use Python for web page development is library which I have developed.

Comment: This should at the very least be four different questions.

Comment: does it make any difference ? I understand to be strict on this if we are talking about incident management, but this is just a question on the public forum.

Comment: This is not a forum. ANd this website has rules. You should have at least read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting

Answer (score 2):

Question zero, i.e. why models: Django's models are a nice abstraction on top of relational database tables – most (if not all) web apps end up having (or being) some sort of CRUD where you manipulate objects or graphs of objects saved in the database, so an object-oriented approach is nice to work with there.

In addition, many features in Django (and libraries that work with Django) are built around models (such as the admin, ModelForms, serialization, etc.).

Question 1: That date should preferably be `datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)`, not a string, but that aside, Django deals with defaults on model instantiation, not necessarily in the database.

Question 2: Because [that's how it's mapped](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0a66aa158a47564fa11ff7aa99ffd3d7d73890ed/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py#L123), presumably to avoid programmers accidentally losing floating-point precision (since MySQL is rather notorious about doing precision-losing conversions "behind your back").

Question 3: Django's ORM is, to be absolutely honest, not the fastest when it generates queries and instantiates model instances. Most of the time, in regular operations, that's not a problem. Depending on what you're doing with those 700 to 800 instances, you may be able to work around that anyway; for instance, using `.values()` or `.values_list()` on a queryset if you don't need the actual instances, just the data.

Regarding direct SQL, **please** don't hard-code any `MySQLdb` calls in a Django app though; Django has very nice "escape hatches" for doing raw SQL:

- You can perform [.raw() SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#django.db.models.Manager.raw) that map into models, or if that's not enough,
- [you can just execute SQL against the database connection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) like you would with `MySQLdb`.

Oh, and one more thing: your model name should be singular (`Quote`) :)

Comment: thanks a lot for all explanations. it was very helpful. those 700-800 entries are quotes (each one has open, high, close, low price and volume. In most cases I need all of them (if you draw candlestick  - which in my case will be done by javascript on the browser. first I need those data via JSON)

Comment: Right. In that case you can easily just do `return JSONResponse(Quote.objects.filter(something).values('tdate', 'ticker', 'open', 'vol'))` and you get `[{"tdate": ...}, {...}, {...}]` out. :)